# Do i need to catch NullPointerException in rest controller?

Tags: java, rest, exception

I know NPE is an unchecked (RTE), and as such we need to prevent it from happening rather than catching it: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072719/effective-java-nullpointerexception-handling.html

But still, let's say I have a REST controller that returns an employee record upon a request. That depends on finding the underlying employee record in the DB before doing update. See the example below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = BENEFIT_VERSION, method = GET)
@PreAuthorize(READ_COMPANY_DATA)
public ResponseEntity get(@PathVariable UUID employerId,
                              @PathVariable Long versionId) {
    log.info("Request to fetch benefit version, employerId: {}, versionId: {}", employerId, versionId);

    BenefitVersion benefitVersion = benefitVersionService.findByEmployerIdAndId(employerId, versionId); <--- Here NPE may be thrown

    if (benefitVersion == null) {
        log.warn("Unable to fetch non-existent benefit version, employerId: %s, ID: %s", employerId, versionId);
        return new ResponseEntity(NOT_FOUND);
    }

    RestBenefitVersion restBenefitVersion = restBenefitVersionAssemblerFacade.toResource(benefitVersion);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(restBenefitVersion, OK);
}
```

The `benefitVersionService.findByEmployerIdAndId(employerId, versionId)` bit may throw NPE.

There is no handler for the NPE associated with this controller, so NPE will simply kill the request processing. Is that all right or would be better to provide a NPE handler for this case to return a meaningful response to the client instead?

Comment: What does the client get? The NPE from your service will never look nice. I would catch it to return a meaningful response that the client can handle. Or even better not let the NPE happen :)

Comment: Only if you have some drappy code that can throw it. Better to check for nulls where necessary before dereferencing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best practice to handle, and provide meaningful message to client side. REST frameworks usually provides way to configure exception handlers, and mappers. Check [this](http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) for Spring. You can find similar mechanism for your REST framework.